# MVVM - ICommand and INotifyPropertyChanged query

Tags: c#, mvvm

All,

Just started w/ MVVM... got few articles that talk abt MVVM... I have 2 queries..

1. Always INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand implementation will be like this? or some other changes required?
2. If I click on some button and need to call some method of model ? How can I achive that?

Thx in advance..

This property is implemented @ model

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
#endregion
```

ICommand -- this is implemented @ VM

```
private ICommand mUpdater;
public ICommand UpdateCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (mUpdater == null)
            mUpdater = new Updater();
        return mUpdater;
    }
    set
    {
        mUpdater = value;
    }
}

private class Updater : ICommand
{
     #region ICommand Members
     public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
     {
        return true;
     }

     public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

     public void Execute(object parameter)
     {

     }

     #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the [<s>framework</s> platform with which I've had more experience](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) ICommand is implemented with a nifty class called `DelegateCommand`.  It basically allows you to implement your `Execute` and `CanExecute`methods else where.
2. On your viewmodel, you would have a command that then executes the method on the ViewModel's Model:

   ```
   public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase<SomeModel>
   {
       //implemented in the base class:
       //public Model SomeModel { get; }

       internal ICommand SomeMethodThatIsReallyOnMyModel
       {
           get
           {
                return _someCommandYouHaveImplementedToDoJustThis;
           }
           //_someCommandYouHaveImplementedToDoJustThis.Execute:
           //Model.SomeMethod()
       }

   //...
   ```

   }